# How do I change discussion settings for all blogs in multisite?

Tags: multisite, comments

I have a multisite with subdirectories.
I want to change the discussion setting so that all comments will be automatically approved.
If there will be need for moderation they will be deleted later.

Is there a way to set this option globally and not per blog ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a plugin for you: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/yd-wpmu-sitewide-options/

The option that you're looking for is:

1. comment_moderation
2. comment_whitelist

Comment: apparently it doesn't work :-(